# Pass core data from selected table cell to new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to pass data (title, ingredients, steps, image) from the selected table cell to a new view controller. But I don't know how to do that. I got lots of errors, so now I'm starting again. Can anyone help me? I'm new to coding. Thanks:-) My code:

**VIEWCONTROLLER.SWIFT**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var recipes = [Recipe]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        fetchAndSetResults()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func fetchAndSetResults(){
        let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = app.managedObjectContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Recipe")

        do {
            let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            self.recipes = results as! [Recipe]
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RecipeCell") as? RecipeCell {
            let recipe = recipes[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(recipe)
            return cell
        } else {
            return RecipeCell()
        }
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return recipes.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "RecipeDetail") {
            //I WANT TO PASS THE DATA FROM THE TABLE CELL TO THE NEW VIEW CONTROLLER (RECIPEDETAILVC)
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

            let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = app.managedObjectContext

            context.deleteObject(recipes[indexPath.row])
            app.saveContext()

            recipes.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

**CREATERECIPE.SWIFT**

```
class CreateRecipeVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var recipeTitle: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeIngredients: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeSteps: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addRecipeBtn: UIButton!

    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        recipeImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        recipeImage.clipsToBounds = true

    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

        imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        recipeImage.image = image

    }

    @IBAction func addImage(sender: AnyObject!) {
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func createRecipe(sender: AnyObject!) {
        if let title = recipeTitle.text where title != "" {
            let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = app.managedObjectContext
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Recipe", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
            let recipe = Recipe(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
            recipe.title = title
            recipe.ingredients = recipeIngredients.text
            recipe.steps = recipeSteps.text
            recipe.setRecipeImage(recipeImage.image!)

            context.insertObject(recipe)

            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print("Could not save recipe")
            }

            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }

}
```

**RECIPEDETAILVC.SWIFT**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class RecipeDetailVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var recipeImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeIngredients: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeSteps: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //I WANT TO DISPLAY THE CORE DATA INFORMATION FROM THE TABLE CELL I SELECTED.
    }
}
```

**RECIPECELL.SWIFT**

```
class RecipeCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var recipeTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeImage: UIImageView!

    func configureCell(recipe: Recipe) {
        recipeTitle.text = recipe.title
        recipeImage.image = recipe.getRecipeImage()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track which item the person clicked.

```
var mySelection: Int?
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    mySelection = indexPath.row
}
```

Then, use that when doing the segue.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)     {
    if (segue.identifier == "RecipeDetail") {
        //I WANT TO PASS THE DATA FROM THE TABLE CELL TO THE NEW VIEW CONTROLLER (RECIPEDETAILVC)
        let recipeDetailControler = segue.destinationViewController as! RecipeDetailViewController

        if let mySelection = mySelection {
            let recipe = recipes[mySelection]
            // add this function to your
            recipeDetailControler.configureRecipeData(recipe)
        }
    }
}
```

Add this function to RecipeDetailViewController:

```
func configureRecipeData(recipe: Recipe) {

    // IMPLEMENT ME

}
```

Comment: Hi ryantxr! Thanks a lot! I'm almost there! But it's giving an error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. 'let recipe = recipes[myselection] is returning nil. Do you know what's going on here?

Comment: 'mySelection' is an optional. And if it does not get set, then this can happen. See edit for my suggested fix.