# How do I segue from a tableviewcell and pass different data from each cell to the next tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I'm trying to practice making list apps with models by making a class to represent each list item. I have a Category class which contains three properties - two strings and one array of strings. Here is the class:

```
class Category {

   var name: String
   var emoji: String
   var topics: [String]
   // (the getCategories method listed below goes here) //  

 init(name: String, emoji: String, topics: [String]) {
    self.name = name
    self.emoji = emoji
    self.topics = topics 
 }
```

In my Category class I have a method to assign values to the categories so I can keep them out of the view controller. This method is listed below:

```
class func getCategories() -> [Category]
{
   let categories = 
    [Category(name:"cat", emoji:"", topics:["paws","tails", "fur", "pussyfoot","purr", "kitten", "meow"]), 
    Category(name: "car", emoji: "", topics: ["motor", "speed", "shift", "wheel", "tire"])
    ]
 return categories
}
```

I have two UITableViewControllers - CategoryTableViewController and TopicsTableViewController; I want the user to be able to tap a category cell in the CategoryTableViewController and then be taken to the TopicsTableViewController where the topics for the category they selected are displayed in a tableview.

So far I am able to get the cell to segue to the TopicsTableViewController but it displays the same topics no matter which category I select.  Here is how I have my didSelectRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue set up in the CategoriesTableViewController...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)  {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as  UITableViewCell!
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "fromCategorySegue") {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as!  TopicsTableViewController
        vc.categories = categories
    }
}
```

It displays the first category (cat) topics on the TopicsTableViewController even if I select the second category (car).

In case it is helpful here is a snippet of some of my code in the TopicsTableViewController...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath       indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {    
    let topic = categories[indexPath.section].topics[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("topicCell",forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = topic

    return cell
}
```

I also have categories defined at the top of TopicsTableViewController as well so I could get the correct row count based on the topics count...

```
var categories = Category.getCategories()
```

I think I'm missing something in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath or in my prepareForSegue.  I think the fact that my topics are an array that is returned within an array of Category from the getCategories() function is screwing me up somehow.

**Note:** 
My segue between the CategoryTableViewController and the TopicsTableViewController was created on the storyboard by ctrl + dragging from the cell in CategoryTableViewController to the TopicsTableViewController.

Any help is greatly appreciate!

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass core data from selected table cell to new view controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116119/pass-core-data-from-selected-table-cell-to-new-view-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is difficult to answer without seeing the full view controllers. From viewing the code you have posted it seems that there is no relationship between the selected cell and the prepare for segue method. For example do you actually use the variable you create in the didSelectCell method? Looks like you didn't. In prepare for segue you just show the same thing over and over so the result is pretty obvious to be honest.

You need to store the index for the selected cell. Then show the corresponding data from your array using that index. Something like the below may work. Need to create a variable at class level called indexForCatergoryToShow.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
    self.indexForCatergoryToShow = indexPath.row
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{
    if (segue.identifier == "fromCategorySegue") 
    {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! TopicsTableViewController
        vc.categories = categories[indexForCatergoryToShow]
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this by making a variable for indexForCategoryToShow at the top of CategoryTableViewController - I have tried declaring it as -> indexForCategoryToShow: Int = 0, indexForCategoryToShow = 0, indexForCategoryToShow = Int.... none of these ways work, I either get an error about initialization or I get a crash from unwrapping an optional and finding nil.  i should note that I made my segue with the storyboard by dragging from the cell on CategoriesTableViewController to the cells in TopicsTableViewController...

Answer (score 1):

In your cell for row at indexPath:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}
```

In your prepare for segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "fromCategorySegue") {
        if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {
            let row = cell.tag
            // pass data to segue.destination
        }
    }
}
```

So you can know from which cell you are selecting.